# Saving user generated content in an iOS App

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, xib, nib, xcode-storyboard

I have a design app that allows the user to move images around to create a design.  I want them to be able to save their designs.

How would I go about doing this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You cannot generate xibs/nibs programmatically.

I suggest that you save your image coordinates as a plist file instead. A plist file can contain an NSArray or NSDictionary of objects, so (for example) build an array of coordinates like this:

```
NSMutableArray *coordinates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UIImageView *view in arrayOfImageViews)
{
    NSString *position = NSStringFromCGPoint(view.center);
    [coordinates addObject:position];
}

[coordinates writeToFile:someFileName atomically:YES];
```

Then you can load it the same way using

```
NSArray *coordinates = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```

Then loop through the array and use it to regenerate your image views.

Obviously this is an oversimplified example as you would need to include the image names and other data in your plist as well, but hopefully you get the idea. Your array would probably actually contain dictionaries, each one containing an image name and coordinate value.